# Crossbrowser php date to javascript date?

Tags: php, javascript

I am building a JavaScript countdown, that needs to rely on the server time but I cant manage to transfers the php time to javascript in a crossbrowser manner. This workes well in all Mordern browsers, but brakes in older ones (Date not defined). If I go with `date("Y-m-d H:i:s)` instead of `date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z)` it works better but not in IE10

```
<?php

 switch ($day) {
    case 'Sat':
        $start = "10";
        $stop  = "16";
        break;

   case 'Sun':
        $start = "11";
        $stop  = "16";
       break;

    default:
        $start = "10";
        $stop  = "19";
        break;
}

 ?>
<script>
     jQuery(function(){

      var open = new Date("<?php echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z",strtotime("today {$start}:00:00")); ?>");
      var end = new Date("<?php echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z",strtotime("today {$stop}:00:00")); ?>");
      var _second = 1000;
      var _minute = _second * 60; 
      var _hour = _minute * 60;
      var _day = _hour * 24;
      var start  = new Date("<?php echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z"); ?>") ;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only format officially recognized by ECMAScript/JavaScript is [ISO 8601 Extended](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15):

> The format is as follows: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

But, this is new with ECMAScript 5. Prior versions left support up to each vendor to decide.

You could try using [timestamps](http://php.net/time) rather than strings.

```
var open = new Date(<?php echo strtotime("today {$start}:00:00") * 1000; ?>);
// ...
var start = new Date(<?php echo time() * 1000; ?>);
```

Both JavaScript and PHP use UTC-based timestamps, just with the difference of seconds (PHP) vs. milliseconds (JS).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Javascript date() is accept the **milliseconds**, or **dateString**.

The **milliseconds** similar to php `time()`.

The **dateString** should be used this format: `October 13, 2012 11:13:00`

By you case, I suggest using `strtotime()` or `time()` to return the timestamp, but you need * 1000 before pass to javascript.

Ref: [W3schools - Date Object Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp)